# Retrieving VARCHAR data containing commas Apache DB

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am using an Embedded Apache DB to store textual descriptions. For example: "John let Steve borrow his bike, which was a mistake." I can write it to the DB no problem, however, when I try to retrieve it using:

```
    SELECT evtText FROM events WHERE eventID = 54
```

This only works providing there is not a comma in the evtText. If the evtText contains a comma I get an SQLException. Which one depends on the word following the comma. Have got a temporary workaround by replacing the comma with -. That, however, is not a long term solution. Is it possible to escape the comma?

Comment: Maybe you could provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Please show the actual code and the full SQLException

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by using a PreparedStatement to insert the data in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding evtText with backticks

Comment: Tried it without success.